# Is there any way to connect to cardano testnet without running the cardano-node on local computer?

Tags: wallet, testnet

Since the KEVM or EVM devnet seem to be crashed, I Want to access the Cardano testnet, but I don't want to run a Cardano node on my machine and sync the info.

so I wonder is there any tool that can be used as a remote Cardano node like the provider or infura in Ethereum?

Maybe Cardano-wallet? I am not sure if it also needs the Cardano-node running. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a tool like Infura's or Alchemy's API, I'd suggest [blockfrost.io](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#section/Available-networks)

They have several standard endpoints you can fetch from, using standard HTTP methods.

Comment: Thanks~ I will have a try

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a hosted solution, have a look at [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/).

Comment: Thanks~ I will have a try